# How to check if an element contains an image?

Tags: javascript, image

How do I check to see if an element contains an image. Can't I do something like this

```
if(document.getElementById("image").src == myImage.src)
```

Comment: Do you mean an element contains an image or if the element itself is an image?

Comment: Im looking for an element that contain a specific image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function hasImage(element, src) {
    var images = element.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        if (images[i].getAttribute("src") == src) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(hasImage(document.getElementById("image"), myImage.src));
```

---

If your browser supports it, you can use [`element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.querySelector)

```
var img = document.getElementById("image")
                  .querySelector("img[src='" + myImage.src + "']");
console.log(img ? "Found" : "Not found");
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to check if an `img` tag with the id "image" has a `src` attribute equal to a different `img` tag?  If so try the following

```
if (document.getElementById('image').getAttribute('src') === myImage.getAttribute('src)) {
  ...
}
```

If you just want to see if it has an `src` attribute at all then you can do the following

```
if (document.getElementById('image').getAttribute('src')) {
  ...
}
```